# Finding all points on a graph with tangent lines passing through a particular point?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

In this particular case, I am trying to **find all points $(x,y)$ on the graph of $f(x)=x^2$ with tangent lines passing through the point $(3,8)$**.

Now then, I know the [graph](http://www.meta-calculator.com/online/?panel-102-graph&data-bounds-xMin=-10&data-bounds-xMax=10&data-bounds-yMin=-7.28&data-bounds-yMax=7.28&data-equations-0=%22y%3Dx%5E2%22&data-rand=undefined&data-hideGrid=false) of $x^2$. What now?

Answer (score 4):

A point on the graph is $(x,x^2)$. The slope from that point to $(3,8)$ is given by: $\frac{x^2-8}{x-3}$. This has to be equal to the derivative at the point for it to be a tangent. So:
$$\frac{x^2-8}{x-3}=2x$$
$$x^2-8=2x^2-6x$$
$$0=x^2-6x+8$$
$$0=(x-2)(x-4)$$
So $x=2$ or $x=4$.
So the points are $(2,4)$ and $(4,16)$.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm not quite following your third step there where you go from $x^2-8=2x^2-6x$ to $0=x^2-6x+8$; am I not seeing a step? I think I see how you got the (2,4) point since $0=(x-2)(x-4)$, but did you just square those values for the point (4,16)?

Comment: I just moved the $x^2$ and $-8$ on the left hand side of the equal sign to the right hand side of the equals sign.
Solving the quadratic gave the answers of 2 and 4. Those are the x-values of the two points, i.e. (2,  ) and (4,  ). To get the y value you need to square the x value (i.e. sub the x back into the equation) to get the 4 and 16, i.e (  ,4) and (  ,16).

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: For a point $(x,y)$ on the graph of $f(x)=x^2$, find the slope of the line between $(x,y)$ and $(3,8)$.

Step 2: Compute the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)=x^2$ at the point $(x,y)$.

Step 3: Set these two slopes equal to each other and find candidate $x$ values.

Step 4: Check your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Either you write the equation of a tangent at $(x_0,x_0^)$2 and check under which condition this equation is satisfied by the $(3,8)$.

Or you write the equation of a line with slope $t$ passing through the point $(3,8)$: $$y-8=t(x-3),$$
and find under which condition this line has a double intersection with the parabola:
$$x^2-8=t(x-3)\iff x^2 -tx+3t-8=0$$
One has a double root if and only if its discriminant:
$$\Delta=t^2-12t+32=(t-6)^2-4=0\iff t=\begin{cases}4\\8\end{cases}$$
Th abscissée ot the points of contact are the double roots: $\dfrac t2=2,4$, and their ordinates $4,16$.